# Returning a number through a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've written a function that has a single parameter - `updateBool`. The function gets the existing value of the calling cell. If `updatebool` is yes, a random number is generated and returned as the new value of the calling cell. If `updateBool` is no (ie not update is required), then it returns the original value of the cell.

The function executes correctly when `updateBool` is yes. However, when it is no, the result returned is "Error: Result was not a number".

I changed the function so I can run it in debug mode - it seems to execute correctly in this mode, both yes and no as parameters work. But as soon as I pass through `updateBool` as a parameter (by means of a reference to another cell), it errors.

```
function testFunction () { 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var writeSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');  

  //for debug execution only
  var callingRow = 4;
  var callingColumn = '4';
  updateBool = 'no'

  //for when calling as function from spreadsheet
  //callingRow = writeSheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  //callingColumn = writeSheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();

  var callingCellRef = writeSheet.getRange(callingRow, callingColumn)
  callingCellValue = Number(callingCellRef.getValue());

  Logger.log('Calling Cell row: %s column: %s', callingRow, callingColumn);
  Logger.log('Calling Cell Value: %s', callingCellValue);

  if (updateBool == 'no') {
   //DONT do any updates
   Logger.log('UpdateBool is no, no update');
   return callingCellValue;   
    }
  else {
    // do updates
    var randomVariable = Math.random();
    Logger.log('UpdateBool is yes, update to: %s', randomVariable);   
    return randomVariable;
  }
}
```

The actual use case is more complex than this (I'm passing through multiple parameters and using those to query a database) but this is the logic that I can't get working. Thanks!

Comment: Function definition should be `function testFunction (updateBool) {`, right? And say `a1` is `7.77`. And then, at the moment when you set `a1` to `=testFunction("something")`, `a1` is not anymore `7.77` but becomes a formula(`string`). So in the function, since `a1` is a string, it cannot be converted into a number.

Comment: I suggest that you keep the data seperated from the update results.

Comment: Could you share the code of how you get the value of updateBool? The function runs correctly when the value is 'yes' because it's the default logic in your function. I believe the problem lies in how/what value you pass to the updateBool i.e. your are not referencing the cell you think you are or the way you get that value is wrong. (This is best guess I can come up with limited code, I could be completely wrong in my assumptions too :))

Comment: @JagannathanAlagurajan the calling cell has a value of "=testUpdateColumn(D4)" where D4 has a value of "yes" or "no". The D4 value can be anything really - just needs to indicate a boolean condition

Comment: @SangbokLee - I did consider that possibility, it why I'm explicitly converting it to a number, ie: `callingCellValue = Number(callingCellRef.getValue());`

Comment: @Jorg Roper One more question, based on reply it seems value of D4 is determined via boolean condition and it is not manually entered? If that is correct, how are you converting true /false to yes and no?

Comment: @JagannathanAlagurajan - the value of D4 is calculated by this function. In the code above, I'm just generating a random number (ie `var randomVariable = Math.random();`). In the real script, it gets the value from a database - I'm just using random here to simplify the testing. I'm converting the value in D4 (ie yes or no) with the if/else statement in the function - yes it should test for extra conditions, capitals etc but again, simplifying for testing

Comment: @JorgRoper As I said, at the moment you type `=testFunction("no")` and hit the enter, that cell's value is not anymore a number. At that moment It becomes a return value of the function. You have to seperate the value cell and the formula(custom function) cell.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work just fine:

```
function testFunction () { 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var writeSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  

  //for debug execution only
  var callingRow = 4;
  var callingColumn = '4';
  var updateBool = 'yes';


  //for when calling as function from spreadsheet
  //callingRow = writeSheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  //callingColumn = writeSheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();

  var callingCellRef = writeSheet.getRange(callingRow, callingColumn);
  var callingCellValue = callingCellRef.getValue();

  callingCellValue = Number(updateBool,callingCellValue);

  Logger.log('Calling Cell row: %s column: %s', callingRow, callingColumn);
  Logger.log('Calling Cell Value: %s', callingCellValue);


}

function Number (updateBool,callingCellValue)
{
if (updateBool == 'no') {
   //DONT do any updates
   Logger.log('UpdateBool is no, no update');
   return callingCellValue;   
    }
  else {
    // do updates
    var randomVariable = Math.random();
    Logger.log('UpdateBool is yes, update to: %s', randomVariable);   
    return randomVariable;
  }

  }
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't think this will assist. In the original code I used "Number" to parse the value as a number type. In this code, the Number function doesn't accomplish that? And I don't understand how it would help return the value???

Answer (score 0):

D4 value is `no`. Note that this value is a string.

`callingCellRef.getValue()` returns `no` and Number of an string returns `NaN`, so the value of `callingCellValue` is `NaN`.

In order to get the value of D4 change

```
callingCellValue = Number(callingCellRef.getValue());
```

to

```
callingCellValue = callingCellRef.getValue();
```